# This PDF document probably uses a compression technique which is not supported by the free parser shipped with FPDI

Tags: php, tcpdf, fpdi

i want to import an existing PDF file using TCPDF and FPDI and add a watermark and a stamp image to my PDF but i have this error

> This PDF document probably uses a compression technique which is not supported by the free parser shipped with FPDI. (See https://www.setasign.com/fpdi-pdf-parser for more details)

i tried using ghostscript but still get the same error,

```
use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi; 
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../../vendor/autoload.php');
use TCPDF;
public function updateMemoirePdf($selectedProject)
{
    $file = public_path("uploads/themes/{$selectedProject->theme}/memoire/{$selectedProject->memoire_path}");
    $newPdfPath = public_path("uploads/themes/{$selectedProject->theme}/memoire/{$selectedProject->memoire_path}_modified.pdf");

if (file_exists($file)) {
    // Créer une instance de TCPDF
    shell_exec( "gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=".$newPdfPath." ".$file.""); 
    $pdf = new FPDI(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false, true);
    $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($file);
    for ($pageNumber = 1; $pageNumber <= $pageCount; $pageNumber++) {
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->setSourceFile($file);
        $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($pageNumber);
        $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 210);
        $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);
        $pdf->SetTextColor(192, 192, 192); // Couleur du texte en filigrane (gris clair)
        $pdf->SetXY(15, 285); // Position du texte en bas à gauche
        $pdf->Write(0, 'Published by Te-Sea Publication');
        $stampImage = public_path('assets/img/te-sea1.png'); 
        $pdf->Image($stampImage, 10, 10, 50, 0, 'PNG');
    }
    $pdf->Output($newPdfPath, 'F');
    $selectedProject->memoire_path = "{$selectedProject->memoire_path}_modified.pdf";
        $selectedProject->save();

                return $newPdfPath;
            } else {
                throw new \Exception('Source PDF not found!');
    }
}
```

Please can someone help me with the solution?

Note: i tried to use TCPDF only but i had this error `call to undefined method elibyy\tcpdf\facades\tcpdf::setsourcefile()` so i tried combining it with FPDI library

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is. What do you want us to add?

Comment: it's an error, so i'm asking if any one has the solution, so if you understant the problem please explain it to me, and with the possible solutions that can be applied here